# How to fetch json data using vuejs component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to access json data from external file using vue component but I am not able to get any output in web page.The below is my code which I have tried.Can  anyone help me out?

The below is Json data that included the models which I want to display on web page

```
{
    "models": [
      {
        "title": "IRIS",
        "project": "ABC",
        "category": "SINGLES",
        "bedrooms": 3

      },
      {
        "title": "LILAC",
        "project": "ABC",
        "category": "DOUBLE",
        "bedrooms": 4

      },
      {
        "title": "ASTER",
        "project": "ABC",
        "category": "SINGLES",
        "bedrooms": 4

      }
    ]
  }
```

```js
Vue.component('single-model', {

  data: function() {
    return {
      myData: []

    }
  },
  template: `<div v-for="model in myData">
              <p>{{model.title}}</p>
              <hr>
            </div>`,

  created: function() {
    this.fetchData();
  },

  methods: {
    fetchData: function() {
      var url = 'j.json';
      axios.get(url)
        .then(function(res) {
          this.myData = res.data.models;

        });
    }
  }
});
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.19.2/axios.min.js"></script>

    <div id="app">
      <single-model></single-model>

    </div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan axios is working fine without component and I am using local file called j.json.

Comment: Try use arrow function `axios.get(url).then((res) => {this.myData = res.data.models;});` I suppose in `vm` is not what you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` on your code is not referring to your Vue Component.

I think, the easiest way to solve this issue is by creating a new variable to refer to your Vue Component

```
fetchData: function() {
      var url = 'j.json';
      var self = this;

      axios.get(url)
        .then(function(res) {
          self.myData = res.data.models;

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. As you might have noticed white running the provided snippet, `template` can have only one child element, using a `v-for` on the outermost element will create multiple children.
2. `this` in your case is not referring to the vue-component in `fetchData` function.

```js
methods:{
 fetchData() {
      var url = '';
      axios.get(url)
        .then((res) => {
          this.myData = res.data;
  });
    }
  },
```

Try replacing with the above snippet in your code.